# CSS appears to not work on any WordPress theme

Tags: themes, css, formatting

I am in the process of updating my website and decided to purge the old content and start from scratch. However whichever theme I use the webpage fails to load properly. It looks like something to do with the CSS, but it is happening across multiple themes - so could it be some core WordPress file missing causing this to break?

Any help would be much appreciated.

My website is https://www.waltonskitchens.co.uk

[Example of using an alternative theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzXas.png)

Comment: First delete cookies from your computer
If the problem is not solved
It may be due to hosting

Comment: What will be easiest may depend on what services your host offers, but one way or the other I'd just try re-installing WP from scratch within whatever guidelines they provide. As for what's causing the issue, stylesheets and other crucial files are either not being found or are (supposedly), though more likely because the files, as you suspect, aren't being found. It may have something to do with what exactly you did to "purge" the content, but I'm not sure isolating the exact mistake would be more efficient than just, as I said, really starting over.

Comment: Most of the resources are going 404. Make sure your WordPress settings are correct and purge any cache implemented by your hosting provider.